# Display HTTP Request Time

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display the time it takes a function to complete in javascript, and then display the time in an alert window that is called on button click, however the alert box doesn't pop up at all when I click the INFO button:

```
var xmlhttp;
function loadXMLDoc()
{
    var start= new Date().getTime();
//loadxmldoc function
   return new Date().getTime()-start;
}
function firebug(){

    alert("Status: "+xmlhttp.status+" "+xmlhttp.statusText+"\nReady State: "+xmlhttp.readyState+"\nRequest Method: "+document.getElementById("selector2").value+"\nTime: "loadXMLDoc().getTime());
}
</script>
```

Button Html:

```
<button id="btn3" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-top:5px;" onclick="firebug();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal"></span> INFO</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your missing a + between these two:

```
"\nTime: "loadXMLDoc().getTime()
```

should be

```
"\nTime: " + loadXMLDoc().getTime()
```

You also need to return a Date object from the loadXmlDoc function:

```
return new Date(new Date().getTime()-start);
```

Comment: You're right, I fixed that and I wish it was the problem but it didn't seem to fix it. Could it have to do with lexical scoping?

Comment: You should see an error being logged withing your browser developer tools, ie firebug, comment out the long alert and replace with simple alert() to see if it pops up

Comment: Well, when I simply delete the loadXMLDoc().getTime() the alert pops up correctly.

Comment: scoping shouldn't be an issue as they are all defined on window object, ensure that script is loaded before button rendered

Comment: Script is loaded in head, button is rendered as last item in the body. I'm very curious what the specific issue is with the loadXMLdoc().getTime()

Comment: I assume that should replace the current return that I have? (I did that but it didn't work).

Comment: I've tried it the new return will give you a date object with number of milliseconds passed when you call getTime on it

Comment: Here's what i currently have:

Comment: return new Date(new Date().getTme()-start);
}

function firebug(){
 
    alert("Status: "+xmlhttp.status+" "+xmlhttp.statusText+"\nReady State: "+xmlhttp.readyState+"\nRequest Method: "+document.getElementById("selector2").value+"\nTime: " + loadXMLDoc().getTime());
}

Comment: Looking good, what's the error now?, use press f12 to see console tab errors in Firefox and IE, chrome dev tools

Comment: index.jsp:182 Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).getTme is not a function

Comment: Super, glad to help you out, was fun, let me know if anything else comes up.